# time being set to the same text views

Tags: java, android, xml

so i have 2 textviews that must take user input being the current time only in half hour slots tho so for example

start time can only be 3:30 or 4:30 not 5 not 4 or 3. if the current time is 4 than the time should default start to 4:30

and finish time has the same rules

i have the time view and picker working

the problem is the time being picked is being set in both start and finish text views. can not find out why 
im still fixing the half hour problem but wish to do that on my own any tips though would be thankfull

```
            public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    Calendar calTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = calTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int min = calTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE );
                    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, min, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
                }
            }

         displayStartTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        DialogFragment startTimePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                        startTimePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "startTimePicker");
                    }
                });

                TextView displayFinishTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finishTimeView);
                displayFinishTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        DialogFragment finishTimePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                        finishTimePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "finishTimePicker");
                    }
                });


          public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
            {
                TextView startTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.startTimeView);
                startTextView.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);

                TextView finishTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finishTimeView);
                finishTextView.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);


            }

         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/finishTimeView"
                android:layout_width="161dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="99dp"
                android:text="Choose Finish Time"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/confirmBooking"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timefinishText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/startTimeView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startTimeView"
                android:layout_width="161dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:text="Choose Start Time"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/finishTimeView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timestartText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateView" />
```

Comment: Could you post at least some code to see what you are trying to do? Or the view picker

Comment: the formating for stack is stopping me trying to post it\

Comment: Put it as a normal text and I'll format it

Comment: just fixed it up i can send the thing as a zip if it easier

Comment: Sure, send it and I'll take a look :)

Comment: all my code is in the question now

Comment: I've posted an answer, could you try it and let me know if it works or not?

Comment: the code you posted that replaces my time picker fragment bit?

Comment: Check edit please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems there, you are implementing this interface `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` which will be called every time a `TimePickerDialog` is closed, so it will get always the last one, what you can do is remove that interface and implement by yourself.

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        //Do the changes to the TextView
                    }
                };
```

And you assign it whenever you want to create the `TimePickerDialog`, also you can remove the `TimePickerFragment.java` and do in the same class at the moment to check if it works, because you'll need to pass it as a parameter then.

And for the 30 min, you need to create a `CustomTimePicker` to do that.

```
public class DurationTimePickDialog extends TimePickerDialog
{
    public static final int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 30;
    private boolean mIgnoreEvent = false;

    public DurationTimePickDialog(
        Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute,
        boolean is24HourView)
    {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        super.onTimeChanged(timePicker, hourOfDay, minute);
        if (!mIgnoreEvent)
        {
            minute = getRoundedMinute(minute);
            mIgnoreEvent = true;
            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
            mIgnoreEvent = false;
        }
    }

    public static int getRoundedMinute(int minute)
    {
        if (minute % TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL != 0)
        {
            int minuteFloor = minute - (minute % TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
            minute = minuteFloor + (minute == minuteFloor + 1 ? TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL : 0);
            if (minute == 60)
            {
                minute = 0;
            }
        }
        return minute;
    }
}
```

With this class that you can create a `TimePickerDialog` as :

```
DurationTimePickDialog durationTimePickDialog = new DurationTimePickDialog(v.getContext(), mTimeSetListener,hour,min,true);
                durationTimePickDialog.show();
```

You'll be able only to accept 30 min, otherwise will not clickable, but IMHO this is not the correct way to do that, with another `widget` would work also.

Hope it helps.

Comment: how can i upload or send my zip file to make it easier for you see my code setup and layout

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dpjul_MI5RFvhGJt--gtVl3Hpv3PPvwP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dpjul_MI5RFvhGJt--gtVl3Hpv3PPvwP/view?usp=sharing

updated zip 

atm after a few fixes i have no java errors but when i click to chose time it crashes